# Facebook Graph API: Object modifier

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What is the object modifier for in the Graph API? Does anyone know?

[image]

Comment: Did you click "**Learn more** about the Graph API syntax"?  That'd be a good start.

Comment: Do you genuinely doubt whether or not I clicked that link?

Comment: Yes, I genuinely doubt that.  If you doubt my doubting you, then you must be new here.  Stack Overflow is infamous for low effort questions.

Comment: If you looked at my reputation you wouldn't doubt whether I was new here. ;) But yeah, I looked into it and couldn't find much.